¿Como cargar fragmentos de un LONGBLOB de MySQL?
Tengo una base de datos MySQL en la que tengo una tabla con un atributo LONGBLOB. Los datos LONGBLOB tienen un tamaño máximo de hasta 4GB lo cual es un problema ya que a menos que me confunda al cargarlo con SELECT en un programa java se meterían los 4GB en la RAM.
¿Habría alguna manera mediante una sentencia SQL (un select) de traer de la base de datos un trozo del LONGBLOB?

Los campos BLOB son tratados en mySQL como strings de bytes:

BLOB values are treated as binary strings (byte strings)

La ventaja de esto es que puedes utilizar funciones de strings con ellos.
Para obtener parte de un BLOB, puedes valerte de la función substring(), indicando la posición de inicio y la longitud dentro del LOB, por ejemplo:
create table prueba (id int, archivo longblob);
insert into prueba values (1, 0x0102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F101112131415161718191A1B1C1D1E1F);
select id, hex(substring(archivo, 10, 6)) from prueba;

Nos retorna
0A0B0C0D0E0F

fiddle
OJO, estoy usando también la función HEX() para obtener la representación hexadecimal de la información binaria. En una aplicación no necesitas invocar a dicha función.
También, si vienes de lenguajes basados en C, debes recordar que, en SQL, el índice del primer caracter (en este caso el primer byte) es 1, no 0.

Dicho todo esto, finalmente, comentar que, si estás almacenando información de varios gigas de longitud en un campo de una base de datos, yo sugiero que re-pienses tu estrategia, pues considero que, si bien los motores relacionales lo soportan, en realidad no son el almacén ideal para este tipo de información.

Muchisimas gracias es justo lo que necesitaba y el apunte de que el primer caracter es 1 habría metido la pata 100%. Lo que he puesto es un ejemplo mas general pero tenía pensado usarlo con imagenes de perfil mas pequeñas para un servidor y no quería que se cargaran las imagenes de todos los usuarios conectados en la ram del servidor. No se si guardar las imagenes de perfil en una BBDD es la mejor opción pero de momento no me se otra (estoy aprendiendo)
